# Unlimited text field type and unordered list with links

Tags: theming

I'm continually amazed at how powerful drupal can be. Im using **Drupal 7** and right now I am curious to see if its possible to **create a field for a custom content type where I enter text that becomes links via an unordered list**. I would love if I could enter this into the CMS without having to go into the code.

I managed to find a way of creating the unordered list by customizing the field template file (field.tpl.php) which is great, but curious if there is a way to wrap the text items in an href.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="link1.com">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="link2.com">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="link3.com">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I found out a perfect module to do just what I wanted called [Link](http://drupal.org/project/link).